# Overlay image of graph on tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm working on creating a small graph in tikz. However, I'm a bit lazy and don't want to create the actual curve in tikz, but I do want the axes and some text to be done in LateX because it looks much nicer. So I'm basically including a graphic and then doing  the tikz picture "on top". However, when I use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{fig12.PNG};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Which isn't quite what I'm looking for =)

When I include the the graphic at the end of the tikz picture, it sits on top of the axes and stuff, and I'd still need to put points and text on top of it. How can I properly position this image?

Comment: Put the graphics in a node: `\node at (0,0){\includegraphics[scale=.5]{fig12.PNG}};` and play with the coordinate if needed.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: @TorbjørnT. sorry about that; I marked it as a duplicate.